# Where can I get the style file of “Welcome to MacTeX” document?

Tags: header-footer

The document [Welcome to MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/src/WelcomeToMacTeX.pdf) is so beautiful. Where can I get its source/style?

Answer (score 5):

The source is included in the MacTeXtras zip archive (http://tug.org/cgi-bin/mactex-download/MacTeXtras.zip), in the folder `/MacTeXtras/Documentation/Sources/`, which contains another zip archive, WelcomeToMacTeX.zip, with the actual source. Snippets from the first page:

```
%slanted and shadowed MarkFelt 
\font\wda="MarkerFelt-Thin:color=0747CC;slant=0" at 42pt%.
\font\wdb="MarkerFelt-Thin:color=C4D1DF;slant=1.75" at 42pt%
```

[...]

```
%cover page showing some capabilities of MacTeX
%shadowed and slanted Welcome to MacTeX in MarkerFelt-Thin
\centerline{\wda Welcome to Mac\TeX}\par%
\centerline{\raisebox{.5\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\wdb Welcome to Mac\TeX}}}
```

[...]

```
%welcome in seven languages 
\centerline{\rotatebox{270}{\wca fogadtatás}%hungarian
\hfil\rotatebox{270}{\wcb ようこそ}%japanese
\hfil\rotatebox{270}{\wcc bienvenida}%spanish
\hfil\rotatebox{270}{\wcd  kaabọ}%yoruba
\hfil\rotatebox{270}{\wce chào mừng}%vietnamese
\hfil\rotatebox{270}{\wcf 歡迎}%chinese 
\hfil\rotatebox{270}{\wcg добродошао}}\par\vspace{36pt}%macedonian
```